# Custom Python Script for SSL-Strip

Tags: python

"Firts of all this stuff is for my university(a challeng) nothing bad is happening in RL"!

Im not quite familier with phyton but, i give it a trie.
The task is to performe a ssl Stripping attack through a phython script.
The output off the script musst be Username and PW (stdout)
My problem is now:

When i download the ssl strip binarie i see a python script which should include the relevant stuff (sslstrip) but, im not soure where i should start here?

I noticed that the two classes ClientsRequest & Stripping Proxy are essential so they are an the bottom.

My problem is how can i i connect the client request class so that it reads the data from the client ?

Im not sure but this could be the config for the port:8080
(the script must listen on 8080)

```
# Standard socket stuff:
host = ''  # do we need socket.gethostname() ?
port = 8080
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(1)  # don't queue up any requests

# Loop forever, listening for requests:
while True:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()
    print "Connection from: " + `caddr`
req = csock.recv(1024)  # get the request, 1kB max
```

I need a little spark in the right direction.

best regards
Rolento

Comment: You said it's a challenge and you try to use someone's else modules? You should build your stuff from the scratch, and understand how you can achieve degrading a connection, i.e. MITM attack.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Loop forever, listening for requests:
while True:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()  #< - this is a blocking call
    print "Connection from: " + `caddr`
#you never end up getting to this instruction
req = csock.recv(1024)  # get the request, 1kB max
```

you have some problems

`sock.accept` will block waiting for a connection ... once you get the connection you print their data and loop right back to the waiting for connection ... when in reality you want to do something with that connection

```
while True:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()  #< - this is a blocking call
    print "Connection from: " + `caddr`
    req = csock.recv(1024)  # get the request, 1kB max
```

will at least recieve a message from the client after accepting the incomming connection

what you probably need to do is hand the connection off to a seperate thread to work with so you can continue to accept new connections , while processing the current connection

Comment: OK im now much further on with the script, currently im at the point where the client is delivering the strippend data. Its stored in a variabel (req2).My problem now is how can i check the req2 for this keywords user and pass ?                                                                   After that i have to use - stdout to "print" it out.